# .png Files are missing after build with electron-builder

Tags: electron-builder

I've started an electron project last month in which I used multiple png files.
After building my app with electron-builder (Settings: Win 32 x64 nsis) and starting my freshly built app I recognized that the png images are missing.
I've also included this snippet in my package.json:

```
 "files": [
        "**/*",
        "*",
        "**"
      ],
```

But it is still not working!
Thanks for your Help,
aphi.

Comment: where are your PNG files located? are they under 'src' folder?

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved?  I'm facing the same problem, but for me it's just *some* PNGs - 2 of 7 are showing up.  Thx.

Comment: Did a little more research - all of the PNGs are in the ASAR (so it's not a problem with electron-builder, I don't think), but only 2 of 7 are displayed.  They're all in the same folder and all of the src attribute values are correct.  For some reason, they're just not being pulled out of the ASAR.  Still researching...

Comment: Created a new question with the results of my research: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49614896/png-files-not-found-in-asar