# PNG files not found in ASAR

Tags: electron, electron-builder, asar

I have an Electron (1.7.10) application that is reporting it can't find 5 of 7 PNG files in my ASAR.  All 7 PNGs are in the same folder, and 2 of them are displayed on screen fine.  The other 5 report **net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND**.

All src attributes for the img tags are dynamically generated and use relative paths (`assets/images/MyImage.png`).  If I extract the ASAR, I can see the files in there, in the correct folder (as referenced by the src attribute).

If I use the console to set the location of my browser to one of the images (`document.location.href = "file:///path/to/app.asar/dist/assets/images/MyImage.png"`) I get the same results - 2 of 7 show OK.

Before packaging my application (with electron-builder), all images show correctly.

Comment: I notice that you have Uppercase in your image name. Is it possible you are developing on Windows (case-insensitive)? The package is platform independent, therefore case-sensitive. Just something worth checking.

Comment: Good point.  Not the problem here, but something to fix anyway.

Comment: I also have similar issue and use angular.. In my case only one png file doesn't get copied during electron-forge make and this png file is the only png file that is png 24.

Answer (score 1):

Let me guess, you are building a react SPA using react-router, and BrowserRouter?

If so, use HashRouter instead. Electron does not work with SPA's route by default, because a SPA route changes, but the resource path is always relative to index.html.

Comment: No.  This was Angular.  Also, 2 of 7 images work fine

Answer (score 1):

I haven't evaluated the other answers, but for my particular case, an extremely solution worked.  I don't believe this is well documented, so it might be fairly common for people to still encounter this issue.  For my particulars, the relevant problem and solution were identified [here](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder/issues/4206#issuecomment-632149122).

To address, add `<base href='./' />` to the index.html (or whatever your starting html file is that hosts your SPA).  This is a complete example of mine:

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <base href="./" />
        <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
        <meta
            name="description"
            content="Web site created using create-react-app"
        />
        <meta
            http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"
            content="script-src 'Self' 'unsafe-inline';"
        />
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/logo192.png" />
        <!--
      manifest.json provides metadata used when your web app is installed on a
      user's mobile device or desktop. See https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-app-manifest/
    -->
        <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
        <!--
      Notice the use of %PUBLIC_URL% in the tags above.
      It will be replaced with the URL of the `public` folder during the build.
      Only files inside the `public` folder can be referenced from the HTML.

      Unlike "/favicon.ico" or "favicon.ico", "%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" will
      work correctly both with client-side routing and a non-root public URL.
      Learn how to configure a non-root public URL by running `npm run build`.
    -->

        <title>React App</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
        <div id="root"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const path = require('path');

path.join(__dirname, 'assets/images/MyImage.png');
```

Comment: Thanks, but it isn't a problem "finding" the image.  2 of 7 work just fine.  The problem is that those files (although in the ASAR) don't seem to wanted to be "pulled out" and displayed.

Comment: That's why it using __dirname. __dirname value is different before asar and after.

Comment: Thanks, but it's not a pathing issue.  All paths are correct, follow the same pattern, and 2 of 7 work.